# Need to mask mobile number using regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I have used the following expression.

```
.replaceAll("\\d(?=\\d{4})", "X")
```

In android studio for the following.

```
Input:- 1234567809
Expected Output:- 12XXXXX809
```

The output which, I am getting after using the above expression:- `XXXXXX7809`

Kindly help to get expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=\d{2})\d(?=\d{3})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sNhbV8/2).

The pattern will match any digit that is immediately preceded with two digits and immediately followed with three digits.

In Java/Android, use:

```
.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{2})\\d(?=\\d{3})", "X")
```